# What's this grey stuff on concrete wall

Tags: concrete, mold, water-damage, rain, putty

This stair handle wall is concrete, and it has been finished with white putty and paint.

[image]

I don't know what's this grey color stuff and any ideas to fix this would be great.

[image]

Comment: And judging by the sky and the water on the railing it's outside and gets rained on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirt, mold, mildew and/or algae.

Wash it, bleach it, possibly pressure-wash it with likely paint removal as a result.

Repaint it once dry with suitable masonry primer and paint for exterior use.

Comment: Thanks , I will try with Bleaching and see how it goes